# How to initiate SMTP outbound traffic via secondary interface - Linux Sendmail

Tags: sendmail

We have sendmail running in a RHEL box. We have two public IP address configured in the same box, one for SAP app and other for Sendmail. First interface will be used for SAP and second for Sendmail.
I have `bind`ed the Sendmail daemon on secondary NIC, but when I send out a mail, traffic is getting initiated via the primary NIC and connection is getting refused as port 25 is blocked for the *this* NIC in the firewall.

Can someone please help me out to resolve this? Should I make changes in Sendmail's config to route SMTP traffic via secondary NIC, or should I play with IPtables to get this done? I need some ideas.

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Christopher

As requested:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
xxx.x.x.32      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth1
10.90.9.96      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         xx.x.x.33       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: What is your routing table? `ip route show` or `route -en`

Comment: route -n O/P
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
xxx.x.x.32    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth1
10.90.9.96      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         xxx.x.x.33    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1

Comment: This is a little bit unreadable but it seems that `eth0`  has no default route so you can only send mails via eth1

Comment: Which interface do you want sendmail to use?

Answer (score 2):

`ip route get $(gethostip -d $NEXTSMTPHOP)` should show the interface that will be used for your outbound traffic. Binding an interface will only influence the listen-address for inbound traffic.

So you need to setup routing in a way that your next SMTP-HOP (hopefully a static IP) is going out through your desired interface.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use marking in iptables to choose routes based on the port.  The only documentation I have seen on doing this is the [Shorewall multiple ISP](http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html) documentation.